# MongoDB: Always receiving 127.0.0.1 when initializing primary node

Tags: mongodb

No matter how I try to initialize my primary node, it always gets the name `"name" : "127.0.0.1:27017"`, therefore any remote node additions in the replica set, fail with this message:

> "errmsg" : "Either all host names in a replica set configuration must
>   be localhost references, or none must be; found 1 out of 2"

Here is my `.conf`

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: mongodb.primary, 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

How should I properly initialize my primary so that it does not bind to `127.0.0.1` only?

The `mongodb.primary` above is resolvable among all machines;

Here is the full error:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.add('mongodb.secondary1:27017')
{
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1552552019, 1),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Either all host names in a replica set configuration must be localhost references, or none must be; found 1 out of 2",
    "code" : 103,
    "codeName" : "NewReplicaSetConfigurationIncompatible",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1552552019, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is clearly stated: the first replica set member is bound to `localhost`

To bind to all IPs *(**Not recommended** to use this without authentication it's ok for testing though)*

```
net:
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

See this document [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp)

> For you case the chances are that the MongoDB instances at DO are bound to localhost by default. However, you might need to bind them to a different IP address using the `net.bindIp` configuration option. Please be advised, this wille expose the MongoDB instance being accessible given they connect to the chosen port. Recommended to enable authentication if a MongoDB instance is bound to a different IP than localhost.